# Get photos from a Google+ album, in JSON format

Tags: javascript, xml, json, google-plus

Based in this post:

[Google Plus Album Urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183212/google-plus-album-urls)

How I can get the response in JSON format, directly from the Google servers? (that means: without parse the xml and convert to JSON from my server).

Comment: Looks like everything is in Google+ Api is in JSON. https://developers.google.com/+/api/ and here shows a call for a photo: https://developers.google.com/+/api/#partial-response

Comment: Yes I know, but I need to use the Picasa API, not the Google Plus API :(.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've noticed, you need to use the Picasa Web Albums API for now, until they get around to a Google+ API. Picasa Web Albums API uses the older Google Data Protocol, which was designed around XML.

You can have Google's servers convert the XML to JSON by providing an ?alt=json parameter to the URL. The rules for how the XML is converted to JSON, as well as other information about this, are documented at https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/json