# Get images from Google Plus album - Authentification

Tags: image, google-plus, photos, picasa

is there any way to get images from Google Plus album e.g. in JSON format. Regarding these topics:

- [Google Plus Album Urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183212/google-plus-album-urls)
- [Get photos from a Google+ album, in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16389174/get-photos-from-a-google-album-in-json-format)
- [Google Plus API get photo albums/videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370554/google-plus-api-get-photo-albums-vidoes)

the way is using the Picasa URL. This works perfectly but only for public albums

Using authkey in URL does not work.
http: //picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/ ... user id ... /album/ ... album id ... ?authkey= ... auth key ... &alt=json

Does anyone have the solution for getting Google Plus album images where not public album is asked (using authkey).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can authorize with google plus and then use its token to request albums from Picasa.
To get the right permissions you should use `gapi.auth.authorize` method with the corresponding scope, which is `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/`

```
var googleClientToken = ''
var options = {
    client_id: googleClientId,
    scope: 'https://picasaweb.google.com/data/ https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
}
gapi.auth.authorize(options, function() {
    googleAccessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token
})
```

Then just fetch the url `https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/USER_EMAIL/?kind=album&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&alt=json&access=all'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PicasaWeb GData API:

- list all of a user's albums
- identify the ID of the album you care about
- fetch the data for that album using alt=json