# Google plus ios sdk, how to get photo albums and images

Tags: ios, image, sdk, google-plus, picasa

How does one get a list of photo albums and list of images in each album for the current g+ user, and for other users which the current user may access - **from within the iOs sdk**.

I have already read about the [api being basically that of Picasa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183212/google-plus-album-urls): i.e https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/USER_ID?alt=json, but I am unsure on how to do that from within the iOs sdk: I guess I need to do the above url request with some authentication, and maybe if the token is the same as g+, use that..

Or should i use the PicasaWeb GData API: as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364103/get-images-from-google-plus-album-authentification)

Or is there a real SDK solution for this in the google+ ios sdk?

Answer (score 0):

t is currently not possible to share images on Google+ with the Google+ iOS SDK.

Comment: It would be good if you could add some links to source of your conclusion.

Comment: You can attach an image to a share to Google+ using the SDK (https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/media) but there is no way of accessing the photos or managing albums within the SDK (source: direct experience, and https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/). Picassweb API is the closest option at the moment.